# Multibrand Parent & Child BUs - Contact management & profile center

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, sfmc-business-unit, child-to-parent, parent-to-child

A potential client has a Parent BU, in which seats the data of one of their brands, and a Child BU in which seats the data of the other brand.
They currently have an issue of unsubscription, since they use the Standard Profile Center > unsubscribed from the CHild BU are automatically as well from the Parent and apparently vice versa.

Question 1: Can we set up 2 custom Profile Centers, one for the Parent one for the Child BU?
2. We have the possibility to implement another BU and migrate the data / campaigns from the Parent to the new Child, which would make of the current Parent more like an Administration BU and not a BU to manage contacts & marketing campaigns.

Is it worthy? Can we keep the architecture as it is and what are the pros & cons?
I'm trying to understand the limitations but there isn't so much documentation available.

Thank you!

---

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 Answer: You can definitely set up 2 Custom Profile Centers. You could do it through your own hosted pages or CloudPages if you have them or a third-party tool. Really up to you and what resources you have. I would then modify the functionality/set it up to how you want it to relate to the Parent Business unit. I would also submit a ticket to Marketing Cloud to remove the constraint for Unsubscribe and Profile Personalization Strings in emails (last step when everything is built & tested).

From SFMC Documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_headers_and_footers.htm&type=5 -

"You can configure your account to ignore this validation, but you remain responsible for including all legally required information in your email messages. Use more personalization strings in your headers as necessary." - 4th Paragraph from the bottom

Question 2 Answer: This is more complicated and is much a strategy/business question as it is a technical question. You would need a discovery call/conversation to know what data you want to bring into the child business unit and how it relates to your current BUs and external systems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Regarding the question 2, this is definitely more complex and time sensitive than just migrating data at a very beginning of a project and it needs to be arbitrated at the client level. Regarding your answer 1, I didn't even know it was possible to request the unbounding of Unsub / Profile Personalization. First time I hear of it. If you happen to have reference articles, I'm taking!

Comment: Sure thing. @ElodieLapp added the documentation in the answer.

Comment: Ohh yes so now I understand what you were mentioning. To be honest, I never use anyway the standard header / footer. Thanks a lot for your help!!